# Trying to set input text with the content of a row table but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two rows of the same table: first is just a td tag with a content. The second is composed by input types. I'm trying to copy the cell content to the input text but it is not working.

I already put an alert and the reference looks ok. Tried text and html methods. None has worked. See the code below:

```js
function removeDesloc() {

    let _total_deslocamentos = $("#qtdDeslocSalvos").val();
    let _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo = _total_deslocamentos - 1;

    // Atualiza Total de Deslocamentos que estao salvos no BD
    $("#qtdDeslocSalvos").val(_total_deslocamentos - 1);
    alert($("#deslocamento_data_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    // Antes de remover efetivamente a linha, copia seu conteúdo como sugestão de inclusão.
    $("#deslocamento_data_inc").val($("#deslocamento_data_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    $("#deslocamento_origem_inc").val($("#deslocamento_origem_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    $("#deslocamento_destino_inc").val($("#deslocamento_destino_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    //$("#deslocamento_uf_inc").val( $("#deslocamento_uf_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo ).text() );
    //$("#deslocamento_local_inc").text( $("#deslocamento_local_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo ).text() );
    $("#deslocamento_hora_saida_inc").val($("#deslocamento_hora_saida_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    $("#deslocamento_tempo_inc").val($("#deslocamento_tempo_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).text());
    //$("#transp_id_inc").text( $("#transp_id_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo ).text() );

    // Remove linha da tabela que contem o deslocamento removido via AJAX
    $("#deslocamento_" + _indice_ultimo_deslocamento_salvo).remove();

    populaLinhaIncDesloc();

}
```

The code process without errors but the input remains without the information.

Comment: Please add comments in English so that more people can understand your question.

Comment: Thanks, @sanketd617. My mistake. First posted question.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, so sorry! I'm new here, and I posted this question but already found my error! I forgot to remove the last call (it cleans everything).

It was a Control+C / Control+V problem.

So so sorry.